# Can't bind to 'ngFormModel' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

I tried using `[ngModel]` in my html file. Although I import FormsModule in app.module.ts, it gives error as

> unexpected token attribute name expected

I use Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with Resharper. AngularJs extension is installed for Resharper. I cannot understand why it doesn't see `ng attributes`.

[image]

api-example.component.html

```
<form [ngFormModel]="searchForm">

    <label for="search" > Search on Youtube</label><br />
    <input ngControl="search" id="search" />'+

</form>

<!--<div *ngFor="#result of results$">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <h3>{{result.snippet.title}}</h3></a>
</div>-->
```

api-example.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/RX';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import {FormsModule, FormBuilder, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'api-app',
    templateUrl: './app/rx/api-example.component.html'
})

export class RxApiExampleComponent {
    searchForm: any
    results$: Observable<any>

    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, private http: Http) {
        const API_URL = ''
        const API_KEY = ''

        this.searchForm = this._formBuilder.group({
            'search': ['',Validators.required]
        })

        this.results$ = this.searchForm.controls.valueChanges
        .subscribe(value=>console.log(value))
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { RxExampleComponent } from './rx/rx-example1.component'
import { RxApiExampleComponent } from './rx/api-example.component'
import {NavBarComponent} from './nav/navbar.component'
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        RxApiExampleComponent,
        RxExampleComponent,
        NavBarComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean`[formGroup]`? Also `*ngFor="#result of` is deprecated. use `*ngFor="let result of` instead

Comment: It doesnt matter. It gives error for all ng attributes like *ngFor. when using *, [] or () it gives 'unexpected token' @yurzui

Comment: Try importing the `CommonModule` from `@angular/common` and adding it to your declarations.

Comment: I added CommonModule to app.module.ts but never changes. @fzxt

Comment: @nevra On top of what yurzui said, it should be `formControlName="search"` instead of `ngControl="search"`

Comment: @AJT_82, thanks for your answer, but my question is general for example same error for "*ngFor"  (10th line)

Comment: what version of Angular are you using? Like yurzui wrote `#` is deprecated, so it would throw error.

Comment: I use angular2, ok, I tried let result of results$, It's ok but my problem is about ng attributes like *ngFor, [ngModel]. Visual Studio doesn't accepted [], (), * things @AJT_82

Comment: AngularJS extension? AngularJS and Angular are two different things. If you have AngularJS extension installed, that would cause errors as well...

Comment: I understand but before I installed this extension, I've got the same error.. @AJT_82

Comment: I can't really tell, you had some syntax problems, which have all been mentioned, ALSO notice, that what you are trying to do with `results$` doesn't contain any "results", it just is the value of the form... http://plnkr.co/edit/GMDPIOWiGDVRDmQXrpst